# What are the security risks of setting Access-Control-Request-Headers to *?

Tags: c#, cors

We have currently enabled CORS on the server and have allowed only certain origins, headers and methods to allowed over CORS.

We are planning to allow all headers to be allowed over CORS, i.e., set the `EnableCorsAttribute.Headers` to `*`.

What are the security concerns/risks I should be aware of?

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate - the linked questions are for a _different_ CORS header and do not answer the specific question about Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't just use * as a cros domain but from a diffrenet reason that you may think,
not all of the browsers by default will allow to use wild card (*) for security reasons, 
so you should just returned as allowed the address of your incoming requests.

If you are providing a service that's open to the all world, so that's what you should do, if not, just noticed that you are open to the all world.